# OSGi Resolution error "osgi.wiring.package"

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, resolution

I'm working on a OSGi project (I'm fairly new with it). It is an existing source code, so I'm adding a new bundle called "io.openems.edge.dieselgenerator", when I do the resolution process I get that it failed with the following message:

```
Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
[<<INITIAL>>]
  ⇒ osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=io.openems.edge.dieselgenerator)
      ⇒ [io.openems.edge.dieselgenerator version=1.0.0.202107141719]
          ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (osgi.wiring.package=io.openems.edge.simulator)
[osgi.cmpn version=7.0.0.201802012110]
  ⇒ osgi.unresolvable: (&(must.not.resolve=*)(!(must.not.resolve=*)))
[ch.qos.logback.classic version=1.2.3]
  ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=ch.qos.logback.core.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
[org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.server version=9.4.35.v20201120]
  ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.alpn)(version>=1.1.3))
```

I see that there's a problem with osgi.wiring.package: (osgi.wiring.package=io.openems.edge.simulator). io.openems.edge.simulator is an existing bundle that I added to my new bundle as a dependencies. Any idea of what's happening? Or should I provide more information that I don't know?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What the message is telling you is that none of the bundles installed in the OSGi container provide/export the package that your bundle or one of its dependencies requires.

It could be that you're missing bundle that provides **org.eclipse.jetty.alpn** package or that you're trying to install your bundle before its dependencies are available.

> Or should I provide more information that I don't know?

It could help other to help you if they knew how your project is setup and where you're running your OSGi bundles i.e Apache Karaf, Eclipse IDE or somewhere else.